# To much blanks in variable (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL )

Tags: javascript, variables, output

```
alert(name);
```

[image]

The output should be **'pikkertonnode_1334187978'**

The 2nd ' is to far away from the end of the text.

This is my code:

```
var name;
var namehelp;
// For individually tab
function refresher() {  

    var url = 'output.php?string=' + choice[0].innerText;   
    var split = url.split("[new]");
    var series = "[" ;
    for (var i = 1; i < split.length; i++)  
    {
          namehelp = split[i];
          var splithelp = namehelp.split(")");
          namehelp = splithelp[1];           
          alert(namehelp);  
          name = "'" + namehelp + "'";
          alert(name);
          series = series + "{ name : " + name + " , data : data[" + (i-1) + "] }," ;   
    }
```

var url is like:

```
http://172.23.133.61:60080/pages/select-multiple-start/output.php?string=[new]frequency%20(Monitor%201)pikkertonnode_1334156507[new]loadvalue%20(Monitor%201)pikkertonnode_1334156507
```

Comment: Its working fine for me I just used the example url and it was fine then. Maybe the problem is pikkertonnode_1334156507 in the requested url ends up with a /n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be your variable contains unwanted spaces.Use the following to remove the spaces

```
alert(name.replace(/\s/g, ""));
```

Comment: No that is the solution, name.replace(/\s/g, ""); 
Before I asked the question I tried it with  name.replace(/ /g, ""); But that did'nt work

Comment: @mishik Its an answer for the question and then why should i add it as a comment..?